# How to search for subtext in text in Tcl?

Tags: list, tcl

I'm new to tcl, I have a list `1-adam 2-john 3-mark` and I have to take input for user of which serial I have to change in list and make it list `1-adam 2-john 3-jane` when user want to change serial 3?

I was trying this:

```
set names [split "1-adam 2-john 3-mark" " "]
puts "Enter the serial no:" 
set serial [gets stdin]
set needle $serial\-
foreach name $names {
    #here I'm trying to find  and overwrite'
}
```

Comment: This is your third question in a row now. What have you tried to solve the problem and can you edit your question to show your code?

Comment: I don't have any internet connection to pc so I'm using my phone to ask and type questions

Comment: And thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good start. To replace an element in a list, you can usually use [`lreplace`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.htm), and for this particular case, [`lset`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm) as well. Both functions need the index of the element to be replaced, and because of this, I would recommend using `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
set names [split "1-adam 2-john 3-mark" " "]
puts "Enter the serial no:"
set serial [gets stdin]
puts "Enter new name:"     ;# Might want to add something like this for the new name
set new_name [gets stdin]
set needle $serial-        ;# You do not really need to escape the dash
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $names]} {incr i} {
    set name [lindex $names $i]
    if {[string match $needle* $name]} {
        set names [lreplace $names $i $i $needle$new_name]
    }
}
puts $names
# 1-adam 2-john 3-jane
```

Using `lset` would be:

```
lset names $i $needle$new_name
```

---

Another way you could do it is to find the index of the element that you need to change using `lsearch`, in which case you won't need a loop:

```
set names [split "1-adam 2-john 3-mark" " "]
puts "Enter the serial no:"
set serial [gets stdin]
puts "Enter new name:"
set new_name [gets stdin]
set needle $serial-

set index [lsearch $names $needle*]
if {$index > -1} {
    lset names $index $needle$new_name
} else {
    puts "No such serial in the list!"
}

puts $names
# 1-adam 2-john 3-jane
```

Comment: After replacing the name, you could `break` the loop.